# What is the most efficient way to update a table during a merge operation?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, indexing

Like many developers, I perform a lot of merge operations with data, specifically SQL Server.

Historically, I have used the old trick of:-

1) Doing a left join on the existing data, and inserting anything I don't have a corresponding record for.

2) After 1), updating rows in my target table.

I have to take a performance hit on 1).  It's unavoidable.  However, on 2), I have been rather profligate.  Instead of just updating stuff that needs updating, I've updated everything I've matched ( whether the underlying data has changed or not ).

Turns out that SQL Server isn't too smart about this sort of update.  It performs no pre-check to determine that what you are about to update isn't the same thing as what you are using to update it.  Hence, updates done along these lines result in a physical write and impact any indexes that reference the field.

So, from my POV, my choices are as follows:-

1) Carry on as normal, basking in the current profligacy of my routine (and refreshing indexes daily on large DBs)

- Pros:  it's easy.
- Cons:  it's crap.

2) Write more UPDATE statements that update a specific field if the field has changed.

e.g.

```
UPDATE
    p2 
SET
    [SpecificField] = p1.[SpecificField]
FROM
    @source p1,
    Dest p2
WHERE
    p2.ExternalKey = p1.ExternalKey
AND COALESCE(p1.[SpecificField],'') <> COALESCE(p2.[SpecificField],'')
```

- Pros:  it's highly specific, only updating when an update is required.
- Cons:  lot of different update statements for tables with many columns.

3) Something infinitely better that the Stack Overflow community suggests.

I'd really like to go with 3).  Are my options really limited to 1 or 2?  Note.  I have looked into MERGE INTO.  Same problems, really.

Comment: SQL Server?  Version? You may be able to use a `MERGE` statement...

Comment: I know that 2008 comes with MERGE INTO, but doesn't that have the same problems when it comes to impact on indexes?

Comment: If you are updating a field where the value didn't change then yes. You can always put `CASE` checks for each field.

Comment: Which is kinda the problem.  Interested in seeing your CASE checks solution to this though, especially if it is achievable in one  statement.

Comment: Did more testing and it doesn't get optimized out, unfortunately....

Comment: What about writing a code library that can, on the one hand, generate all permutations of update stored procedures that you care to have, and on the other hand, choose the correct stored procedure to execute given the state of the object in memory. I did something like this when I was stuck implementing a db-side paged,sorted, and filtered list solution. (Basically option 2 but managed programatically).

Comment: Weirdly enough, Griffin - that may be the option I end up taking.  I'm increasingly of the view that a holistic approach is the proper way to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

With `MERGE INTO`, you have the option of adding an additional search clause to a `WHEN (NOT) MATCHED` clause.  For example,

```
MERGE INTO table_to_upsert AS target
 USING source_table    AS source
    ON target.key1 = source.key1
   AND target.key2 = source.key2
   AND target.key3 = source.key3
WHEN MATCHED AND (target.value <> source.value) THEN
            UPDATE SET target.value     = source.value,
                       target.timestamp = source.timestamp
WHEN MATCHED AND (target.userid <> source.userid) THEN
            UPDATE SET target.userid    = source.userid,
                       target.timestamp = source.timestamp
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT (key1, key2, key3, 
                    value, userid, timestamp)
            VALUES (source.key1, source.key2, source.key3,
                    source.value, source.userid, source.timestamp)
```

However, this doesn't really solve your problem if multiple columns are updated at a time, the `MERGE` would take the first `WHEN (NOT) MATCHED` that evaluates true (similar to a `CASE` statement).

Comment: And it was all going brilliantly until that last sentence!

(This may still end up being the answer though, unfortunately).  Appreciate the input, sir!

Comment: Did you try this? I get `An action of type 'WHEN MATCHED' cannot appear more than once in a 'UPDATE' clause of a MERGE statement.` in SQL Server 2012. Is it different in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: From the [merge documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx). "The MERGE statement can have at most two WHEN MATCHED clauses."...."If there are two WHEN MATCHED clauses, then one must specify an UPDATE action and one must specify a DELETE action"

Comment: Aw.  I mostly use DB2 (which allows this), and didn't see that statement when I scanned the [BOL page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) for `MERGE`.  Sorry.  :(

Comment: This solution could still work if you [emulate the multiple `WHEN MATCHED .. THEN UPDATE` statements in SQL Server using `CASE` expressions](https://blog.jooq.org/2020/04/10/the-many-flavours-of-the-arcane-sql-merge-statement/).